# Why does CC not see my function definition in header?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm writing a simple application in ANSI C. I am using GCC in a Unix environment.

I have the following sample application:

```
    //main.c

#include "foo.h"

int main()
{

int result;

result = add(1,5);

return0;
}
```

Header:

```
  //foo.h
    #ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
    #define FF_H_INCLUDED

    int add(int a, int b);

    #endif
```

Implementation:

```
//foo.c

int add(int a, int b)
{
return a+b;
}
```

I am compiling my program with the following command:

```
 cc main.c -o main.o
```

The compiler complains that 'reference to `add` is undefined'. Is this a linking problem? How do properly make use of my header?

Thanks!

Comment: What is normally designated `ANSI C` does not like `//` comments.

Comment: @pmg: this "normal" designation is outdated by more than a decade. Speaking in present day, ANSI C is C99.

Comment: @R..:C99 is an ISO standard not and ANSI standard. So ANSI C specifically refers to C89.

Comment: @Clifford: No, the ANSI standard is aligned with the ISO standard. You can even get a copy of the C99 standard through ANSI if you want to pay them.

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe it's time to upgrade, even though most people use a C89 (C90, C95) compiler with extras anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compile both your source files together:

```
cc main.c foo.c -o main
```

Also, in this case, `-o` produces an executable, so calling it `main.o` can be misleading.

---

Yet another tidbit, though unrelated to the question: the `#ifndef` and `#define` in `foo.h` don't match.

Comment: And a second tidbit - while not strictly necessary, it would be a good idea to put a `#include "foo.h"` into `foo.c` to ensure that the function definition of `add()` in `foo.c` matches up with the declaration that everyone sees.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Oh yes, that too.

Comment: Awesome! So do you generally start by creating a makefile? I can see how the list of source files could get large fast.

Comment: @Nick: Indeed, that's exactly why makefiles were invented.

Comment: @Nick:  Or spare yourself the pain and use an IDE that will generate the makefile (and critiaclly all the dependencies) for you (or its equivalent).  For most projects that will suffice.

Comment: @Clifford Is there a good IDE for C that you can recommend? I have used Geany.

Comment: @Nick: I have no great experience of Unix IDE possibilities, but perhaps Eclipse with CDT or K-Develop.

Answer (score 1):

The header is not your current problem. Your current problem is that you're not compiling the `add` function definition in `foo.c`.

Try

```
cc main.c foo.c -o main.o
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compile main.c into an assembled object file, you need to prevent gcc from trying to link. This is done via

```
cc -c main.c -o main.o
```

You can compile all other object files, then when you have all of your object files ready, you simply do

```
cc main.o obj1.o anotherOBJ.o -o myExecutableBinary
```

Answer (score 0):

"undefined reference" is a *linker* error, not a compiler error.

The compiler sees the *declaration* in the header, but you have not compiled or linked the *definition* in foo.c.  Your title uses the term *definition* incorrectly.